# Implement Atwood's Equipping our ASCII armor in PHP

Tags: c#, php, algorithm, encoding, ascii85

I'm trying to implement in PHP something similar to Jeff Atwood's 
[Equipping our ASCII armor](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/equipping-our-ascii-armor.html).
Here's [C# Implementation of ASCII85](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/c-implementation-of-ascii85.html).

Here's [PHP Implementation of ASCII85](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/20092.html)

Here's how I convert the string to byte array:

```
$byteArr = str_split($uid);
foreach ($byteArr as $key=>$val) {
     $byteArr[$key] = ord($val); 
}
```

And what? now :) How to encode this byte array using ASCII 85 to get shorter UID?

Comment: the link to the PHP implementation is the same as the C# one.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["A shorter UUID, ASCII85 with PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325000/a-shorter-uuid-ascii85-with-php) ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the PHP implementation (your link is not working).

If you use [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4052-PHP-Encode-and-decode-data-using-the-ASCII85-algorithm.html), then the code is easy:

```
<?php
include("ascii85.php"); 

$a = new ASCII85();
$uid = "YOUR-UID-AS-A-STRING"; 

$en = $a->encode($uid); 
$de = $a->decode($en); 

echo $en."\n\n".$de;
```

Comment: This encodes and decodes, bud `$en` is longer than `$uid`, and the point is to make it shorter.

Comment: Could you show us an example og uid and the generated ascii85?

Comment: `$in = 22da5537-de54-459d-9b33-f40f2101143b`, `$out = <~1,<BK2)R0K/S&EM1bCOA3Fj^%@P]elAi)2R1,1I;0f1[q~>`